# Symfony 5 form : 2 dynamic select

Tags: forms, symfony, dynamic, symfony-forms, symfony5

I am using Symfony 5. I have managed to link up to two select box with form events, but I need to have three dynamic select box. This is the relation between my entities: category(Famille) -> sub_category(sous_famille) -> sub_sub_category (sous_sous_famille). The sub_sub_category is linked to an Article entity like this:

a category -> many sub_categorys
a sub_category -> many sub_sub_category
a sub_sub_category -> many articles

When I add a new article, I should be able to select a Category and have the sub_category dropdown updated in accordance with category selection; the same thing for the sub_sub_category dropdown after I have selected a sub_category. I have made things work for category and sub_category following a [french video][1] because the one in Symfony guide doesn't work(i don't know why).
This is the Category(Famille) entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=FamilleRepository::class)
 * @UniqueEntity("fam_code")
 */
class Famille
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255,unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $fam_code;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $fam_libelle_a;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $fam_libelle_f;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=SousFamille::class, mappedBy="fam_code")
     * 
     */
    private $sousFamilles;
...
}
```

This is the sub_category(sous_famille) entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=SousFamilleRepository::class)
 * @UniqueEntity("sf_code")
 */
class SousFamille
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $sf_code;

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Famille::class, inversedBy="sousFamilles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="fam_code", referencedColumnName="fam_code",nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $fam_code;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $sf_libelle_a;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $sf_libelle_f;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=SousSousFamille::class, mappedBy="sf_code")
     */
    private $sousSousFamilles;
...

}
```

This is the sub_sub_category(sous_sous_famille):

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=SousSousFamilleRepository::class)
 * @UniqueEntity("ssf_code")
 */
class SousSousFamille
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255,unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $ssf_code;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=SousFamille::class, inversedBy="sousSousFamilles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="sf_code", referencedColumnName="sf_code",nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $sf_code;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $ssf_libelle_a;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $ssf_libelle_f;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Article::class, mappedBy="ssf_code")
     */
    private $articles;

    /**
     * @return Collection|Article[]
     */
    public function getArticles(): Collection
    {
        return $this->articles;
    }
...
}
```

this is the article entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ArticleRepository::class)
 * @UniqueEntity("art_code")
 */

class Article
{

 /**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255,unique=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
private $art_code;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=SousSousFamille::class, inversedBy="articles")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ssf_code", referencedColumnName="ssf_code",nullable=false)
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
private $ssf_code;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
private $art_libelle_a;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
private $art_libelle_f;
...
```

}

**UPDATED !!!**
i have two forms, a ArticleType form and a CategorySelectionType form like this:

CategorySelectionType :

```
class CategorySelectionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('fam_code', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Famille::class,
                'placeholder' => 'Choisir une Catégorie',
                'required' => 'true',
                'mapped' => false,
                'query_builder' => function (FamilleRepository $code) {
                    return $code->createQueryBuilder('c')->orderBy('c.fam_libelle_f', 'ASC');
                }
            ])
            ->add('sf_code', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => SousFamille::class,
                'mapped' => false,
                'required' => true,
                'placeholder' => 'Choisir une Sous Catégorie',
                'query_builder' => function (SousFamilleRepository $code) {
                    return $code->createQueryBuilder('c')->orderBy('c.sf_libelle_f', 'ASC');
                }
            ]);
        $fm = function (FormInterface $form, Famille $fam = null) {
            $sf = (null === $fam) ? [] : $fam->getSousFamilles();
            $form->add('sf_code', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => SousFamille::class,
                'choices' => $sf,
                'mapped' => false,
                'required' => true,
                'placeholder' => 'Choisir une Sous Catégorie',
                'query_builder' => function (SousFamilleRepository $code) {
                    return $code->createQueryBuilder('c')->orderBy('c.sf_libelle_f', 'ASC');
                }

            ]);
        };
        $builder->get('fam_code')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $e) use ($fm) {
                $fam = $e->getForm()->getData();
                $fm($e->getForm()->getParent(), $fam);
            }
        );
    }
..}
```

ArticleType:

```
    class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('art_code', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Code Article', 'required' => 'true'])
            ->add('art_libelle_a', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Libellé Article en Arabe', 'required' => 'true'])
            ->add('art_libelle_f', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Libellé Article en Français', 'required' => 'true'])
            ->add('ssf_code', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => SousSousFamille::class,
                'choices' => $options['ssfs'],
                'placeholder' => 'Choisir une Sous Sous Catégorie',
                'required' => 'true',
                'query_builder' => function (SousSousFamilleRepository $code) {
                    return $code->createQueryBuilder('c')->orderBy('c.ssf_libelle_f', 'ASC');
                }
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Article::class,
            'ssfs' => [],
        ]);
    }
}
```

In the controller:

```
/**
     * @Route("/ajoutArticle", name="app_ajoutA")
     */
    public function ajoutA(Request $req, EntityManagerInterface $em, SousFamilleRepository $ssrep): Response
    {
        $step = 1;
        $art = new Article();
        $sel = $this->createForm(CategorySelectionType::class);
        $sel->handleRequest($req);
        $ssf = [];
        if ($sel->isSubmitted() && $sel->isValid()) {
            $rep = $sel->get('sf_code')->getData();
            $ssf = $ssrep->find($rep->getSFCODE())->getSousSousFamilles();
            $step = 2;
        }
        $form = $this->createForm(ArticleType::class, $art, ['ssfs' => $ssf]);
        dd($req->get('ssf_code'));
        $form->handleRequest($req);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $em->persist($art);
            $em->flush();
            $this->addFlash('success', 'Article créé avec succès !');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_article');
        }

        return $this->render('fr/gestion-articles/Articles/ajoutA.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView(), 'sel' => $sel->createView(), 'step' => $step]);
    }
```

here is my script template:

```
<script>
window.onload = () => {
let fam = document.querySelector("#category_selection_fam_code");
fam.addEventListener("change", function () {
let form = this.closest("form").closest("form");
let data = this.name + "=" + this.value;
fetch(form.action, {
method: form.getAttribute("method"),
body: data,
headers: {
"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset:ut_8"
}
}).then(response => response.text()).then(html => {
let content = document.createElement("html");
content.innerHTML = html;
let nouvSelect = content.querySelector("#category_selection_sf_code");
document.querySelector("#category_selection_sf_code").replaceWith(nouvSelect);
})
});
}
</script>
```

But I have new problem, when submitting the form (ArticleType), the field ssf_code is set to null i don't know why it didn't take the value that i selected.
can you please help me?
[1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7tdb30evUk

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the class diagram for your category class need to be a **[recursive relation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-relationships-in-er-diagrams/)**, which where you will need to add a parent attribut, because the way you are doing it is not flexible and very limited (imagine you need to add a future subcategory SousSousSousCategory).
And the maintenance of the code will be difficult in case you need to add an attribut or a method to Famille, you need to add the same to every subcategory.

Check this image to understand
[image]

You need set your class this way

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\FamilleRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=FamilleRepository::class)
 */
class Famille
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $fam_code;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $fam_libelle_a;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $fam_libelle_f;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Famille::class, inversedBy="sous_familles")
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Famille::class, mappedBy="parent")
     */
    private $sous_familles;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->sous_familles = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getFamCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->fam_code;
    }

    public function setFamCode(string $fam_code): self
    {
        $this->fam_code = $fam_code;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFamLibelleA(): ?string
    {
        return $this->fam_libelle_a;
    }

    public function setFamLibelleA(string $fam_libelle_a): self
    {
        $this->fam_libelle_a = $fam_libelle_a;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFamLibelleF(): ?string
    {
        return $this->fam_libelle_f;
    }

    public function setFamLibelleF(string $fam_libelle_f): self
    {
        $this->fam_libelle_f = $fam_libelle_f;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getParent(): ?self
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    public function setParent(?self $parent): self
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|self[]
     */
    public function getSousFamilles(): Collection
    {
        return $this->sous_familles;
    }

    public function addSousFamille(self $sousFamille): self
    {
        if (!$this->sous_familles->contains($sousFamille)) {
            $this->sous_familles[] = $sousFamille;
            $sousFamille->setParent($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeSousFamille(self $sousFamille): self
    {
        if ($this->sous_familles->contains($sousFamille)) {
            $this->sous_familles->removeElement($sousFamille);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($sousFamille->getParent() === $this) {
                $sousFamille->setParent(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

This code is generated with php bin/console make:entity command

Comment: hi, the problem is that I can't modify the entities, I need to use them as I showed in my question.